# Bayes Theorem Problem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

An insurance company classifies customers as accident-prone or not accident-prone. An accident-prone customer has a 0.3 probability of submitting a claim each year. A
customer who is not accident-prone has a 0.1 probability of submitting a claim each year.
One fifth of the customers are accident-prone. What is the probability that a randomly
chosen customer will submit a claim in the next year?

My solution: Let $A=$ {person is accident prone}, $B=$ {person is not accident prone}, and $C=$ {person will submit a claim}. We know$$P(C|A)=0.3, P(C|B)=0.1$$
My guess is that we have to solve for P(C), but I'm not sure if that is right.

Comment: Yes we have to solve for $P(C)$. And we also know $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ so to get $P(C)$ we have to .... ?

Comment: You **also** know $P(A)=0.2$ and $P(B)=0.8$, since *one fifth* of customers are accident prone.

Comment: The probability here somehow seems skewed for me. Accident prone people only happen with a probability of 20% yet given that you are accident prone you file a claim with probability 30%? The latter must always be smaller than the former. I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Max0815 If you are accident-prone, then you file about one claim every three years. If you are not accident-prone, then you file about one claim every ten years.

Comment: @SuzuHirose no but the question is basically saying P(C|A)>P(A)

Comment: $$P(C|A)={P(C,A)\over P(A)}$$

Comment: @SuzuHirose what? wasn't the formula for that $$P(C|A)={P(C\cap A)\over P(A)}$$ Regardless of which P(A) is still the denominator, meaning it should be always bigger or equal to events that rely on it...

Comment: No, P(C|A) can be 1 even if P(A)=1/10000. For example, the chance that you win the lottery is 1 in 10000, P(max wins)=0.0001, but it is certain that you will buy me a big present if you win, so P(big present|max wins)=1.

Comment: Oh, but on the whole given that you win the chance of buying a present would still be 1/10000. I guess I misinterpreted the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Call the non-accident prone people $\bar A$ (read as "not A" or "A bar") then
$$
P(C|A)=0.3\\
P(C|\bar A)=0.1\\
P(A)=0.2\\
P(\bar A)=1-P(A)=0.8
$$
since the person is chosen randomly, and finally

> $$P(C)=P(C|A)P(A)+P(C|\bar A)P(\bar A).\\$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not require Bayes Theorem as the title suggests. It would require, for instance, if the question were "$C$, a claim, was observed, what is the probability of being submited by an accident prone person $A$?". Translating into probabilities the question is
$$\text{Pr}(A|C)=?$$
Now you might benefit from using Bayes theorem:
$$\text{Pr}(A|C)=\dfrac{\text{Pr}(C|A)\text{Pr}(A)}{\text{Pr}(C)}$$
As you have $\text{Pr}(C|A)=0.3$ and $\text{Pr}(A)=0.2$ your problem would be finding out $\text{Pr}(C)$.

By the "Law of Total Probabilities":
$$\text{Pr}(C)=\text{Pr}(C|A)\Pr(A)+\text{Pr}(C|B)\Pr(B)$$
as $A$ and $B$ are 2 events that are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive. Making the substitutions you will find
$$\text{Pr}(C)=0.3\times 0.2 + 0.1\times 0.8=0.14\ \  \text{and}\ \ \text{Pr}(A|C)=\dfrac{0.06}{0.14}=3/7.$$